# Rounding date by multiple weeks

Tags: javascript, date, epoch

It is easy to round dates to the start of the current week like so:

```js
function roundWeek() {
    var current = new Date();
    var startOfWeek = current.getDate() - current.getDay();
    console.log(new Date(current.setDate(startOfWeek)));
}
roundWeek();
```

This works fine when rounding by one week, but it gets a bit more complex when rounding by multiple weeks.

For instance, say I would like to round in three-week periods. I know this would require an epoch (such as `new Date(0)`) to be able to properly calculate the starting date of the three-week period, but this too causes an issue:

January 1, 1970 (which is `new Date(0)`) occured on a Thursday, so assuming I used it in the following manner, it would always calculate the start of the week to be on a Thursday:

```js
function roundWeek(weeks) {
    var current = new Date();
    const WEEK_IN_MS = 60*60*24*7*1000; //sec * min * hr * day * ms
    var index = Math.floor( (current.getTime() / (WEEK_IN_MS*weeks)) );

    var startOfPeriod = new Date( index * WEEK_IN_MS*weeks );
    console.log( startOfPeriod );
}
roundWeek(3);
```

How can this be modified so that it properly starts on a Sunday instead of a Thursday? Is there a better way of doing this? **And most importantly: Would a leap year cause issues with this?**

Comment: `new Date(0)` is Thursday UTC, but locally Wednesday for those with negative timezone offsets. Also, many places and administrations start their week on Monday, not Sunday. Some start on Saturday. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide whether you want the three-week period to start the Sunday before Jan 1, 1970 (12/28/69) or after. For example, which Sunday would Jan 14, 1970 round to? Then you can calculate the difference between Thursday and either the previous Sunday or next Sunday and add or subtract (depending on the decision you made) that to your rounded solution.

Here's a variation of you function that also takes a date as input for testing.

```js
function roundWeek(weeks, d) {
  var current = new Date(d);
  var first_sunday = 60 * 60 * 24 * 4 * 1000 // seconds between Sunday and Thursday
  const WEEK_IN_MS = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 1000; // week in ms
  var index = Math.floor((current.getTime() / (WEEK_IN_MS * weeks)));
  console.log(`${weeks}-week periods from ${d.getMonth()+1}/${d.getDate()}/${d.getFullYear()} ${index}`)

  var startOfPeriod = new Date(index * WEEK_IN_MS * weeks - first_sunday);
  console.log("1st day of period:", startOfPeriod);
}
// round to three weeks starting Sunday before Jan 1 1970

roundWeek(3, new Date('January 2, 1970')); // Dec 28, 1968
roundWeek(3, new Date('January 14, 1970')); // Dec 28, 1968
roundWeek(3, new Date('January 22, 1970')); // next three weeks
roundWeek(3, new Date('May 16, 2018')); // since today. Sundaay May 6
```

Since leap years don't change how long a week is, they should be irrelevant.

Comment: Note that daylight saving shifts are typically applied on or near the start of Sundays, so your "*seconds between Sunday and Thursday*" will not always be correct twice per year where daylight saving occurs (and is actually milliseconds). You're parsing a string, which is unreliable and should be treated as local, but doing calculations using UTC values. I expect there to be many "edge cases" that produce unexpected results.